# How can I get a Path from a raw C string (CStr or *const u8)?

Tags: rust, c-strings, ffi

What's the most direct way to use a C string as Rust's `Path`?

I've got `const char *` from FFI and need to use it as a filesystem path in Rust.

- I'd rather not enforce UTF-8 on the path, so converting through `str`/`String` is undesirable.
- It should work on Windows at least for ASCII paths.

To clarify: I'm just replacing an existing C implementation that passes the path to `fopen` with a Rust stdlib implementation. It's not my problem whether it's a valid path or encoded properly for a given filesystem, as long as it's not worse than `fopen` (and I know `fopen` basically doesn't work on Windows).

Comment: Use [`CString::into_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.into_bytes) with [`OsStringExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStringExt.html) followed by `PathBuf::from` on Unix and `String` on Windows.

Comment: @BurntSushi5 But this would include an allocation and copying the string, right? The way I understood this question is that Kornel wants to avoid that and just work with a given c-string (right?). I expected there to be a conversion function from `CStr` to `OsStr`, but I can't find such a function :confused:

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an alloc-free approach, which is a bit intriguing but reflects the safety that we wish to impose on strings.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Isn't `OsStrExt::from_bytes` such function? AFAICT an `OsStr` can be produced from a `CStr` using `OsStrExt::from_bytes(cstr.to_bytes())`. This will obviously only work on Unix, but that's unavoidable, since Rust on Windows uses a native `OsStr` implementation incompatible with `char *`. :/

Comment: @E_net4 I suppose an approach that is alloc-free where possible could be hacked together by implementing a `Cow`-like enum for C-backed paths. On Unix the enum would expose a cstring-backed `OsStr&` and on Windows it would allocate an `OsString` and expose its underlying `OsStr&`.

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes, by alloc-free I meant something that would never allocate, even conditionally.

Comment: You can't have alloc-free and portability because you need to deal with the fact that Windows paths might be UTF-16 encoded. You can get alloc-free on Unix using `OsStrExt`.

Comment: "This will obviously only work on Unix" -- it's only "obvious" because Rust is so broken. "but that's unavoidable, since Rust on Windows uses a native OsStr implementation incompatible with char *. " -- this is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I've learned:

- `Path`/`OsStr` always use WTF-8 on Windows, and are an encoding-ignorant bag of bytes on Unix.
- They **never ever** store any paths using any "wide" encoding like UTF-16 or UCS-2. The Windows-only masquerade of `OsStr` is to hide the WTF-8 encoding, nothing more.
- It is extremely unlikely to ever change, because the standard library API supports creation of `Path` and `OsStr` from UTF-8 `&str` without any allocation or mutation of memory (i.e. `as_ref()` is supported, and its strict API doesn't leave room to implement it as anything other than a pointer cast).

Unix-only zero-copy version (it doesn't even depend on any implementation details):

```
use std::ffi::{CStr,OsStr};
use std::path::Path;
use std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt;

let slice = CStr::from_ptr(c_null_terminated_string_ptr_here);
let osstr = OsStr::from_bytes(slice.to_bytes());
let path: &Path = osstr.as_ref();
```

On Windows, converting only valid UTF-8 is the best Rust can do without a charade of creating WTF-8 `OsString` from code units:

```
…
let str = ::std::str::from_utf8(slice.to_bytes()).expect("keep your surrogates paired");
let path: &Path = str.as_ref();
```

Answer (score 3):

Safely and portably?  Insofar as I'm aware, there isn't a way.  My advice is to demand UTF-8 and just *pray* it never breaks.

The problem is that the only thing you can really say about a "C string" is that it's NUL-terminated.  You can't really say anything meaningful about how it's *encoded*.  At least, not with any real certainty.

Unsafely and/or non-portably?  If you're running on Linux (and possibly other modern *NIXen), you can *maybe* use [`OsStrExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html) to do the conversion.  This only works assuming the C string was a valid path in the first place.  If it came from some string processing code that *wasn't* using the same encoding as the filesystem (which these days is generally "arbitrary bytes that look like UTF-8 but might not be")... well, you'll have to convert it yourself, first.

On Windows?  *Hahahaha.*  This depends on where the string came from.  C strings embedded in an executable can be in a variety of encodings depending on how the code was compiled.  If it came from the OS itself, it could be in one of *two* different encodings: the thread's OEM codepage, or the thread's ANSI codepage.  I never worked out how to check which it's set to.  If it came from the console, it would be in whatever the console's input encoding was set to when you received it... assuming it wasn't piped in from something else that was using a different encoding (hi there, PowerShell!).  All of the above require you to roll your own transcoding code, since Rust itself avoids this by never, *ever* using non-Unicode APIs on Windows.

Oh, and don't forget that there is *no* 8-bit encoding that can properly store Windows paths, since Windows paths are "arbitrary 16-bit words that look like UTF-16 but might not be". [1]

... so, like I said: demand UTF-8 and just *pray* it never breaks, because trying to do it "correctly" leads to madness.

---

[1]: I should clarify: there *is* such an encoding: WTF-8, which is what Rust uses for `OsStr` and `OsString` on Windows.  The catch is that nothing *else* on Windows uses this, so it's never going to be how a C string is encoded.

Comment: @red75prime: But you absolutely cannot assume that all paths will be ASCII.  Technically, you can't even assume that all possible encodings have ASCII as a common subset, since there are non-ASCII encodings still usable on Windows.  But once you reach that point, it's hard to continue caring.

Comment: The Unix remark is too pessimistic. A `const char *` received from FFI is meant to be passed to functions such as `fopen()` (this is what any C code would do), so the OP needn't care about the encoding it's in. On the Rust side, that's precisely what `OsStrExt::from_bytes` is *for*. With the Windows part I couldn't agree more.

Comment: @user4815162342: There is nothing in the question about *where* this string is coming from, only that it's a C string.  It could be coming from a database that encodes all it's strings in EBCDIC for all I know.

Comment: That's a theoretical possibility, but I suspect the OP would have mentioned that, or would have referred to the data as `uint8_t *` or equivalent. The fact that the OP wants to "use the `const char *` as a filesystem path" indicates that the file names are fine as they are, content-wise, but it takes some effort to convince Rust of the fact. (Going through strings enforces UTF-8, for example.)

Comment: *there is no 8-bit encoding that can properly store Windows paths* -- this is obviously nonsense; everything in memory has an 8-bit encoding. *since Windows paths are "arbitrary 16-bit words that look like UTF-16 but might not be* -- and POSIX paths are arbitrary byte sequences that don't contain NULs (with some fine print about slashes). None of this is relevant. Just as POSIX OS's don't check that paths are valid Unicode, neither does Windows. Rust breaks the round trip on Windows; other languages don't.

Comment: *C strings embedded in an executable can be in a variety of encodings depending on how the code was compiled. ...* -- All of which is, of course, also true on POSIX. And good luck trying to write fsck/chkdsk in the Rust "systems programming" language. D, e.g., doesn't have this problem because it understands that abstractions leak and system programmers need them to leak, and so it allows viewing byte sequences however the programmer wants, and only enforces Unicode if/when the programmer wants that.